# lxml get full ext of element

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following xml:

```
<text>test<br/><br/><a href="/nature/19700707">All you need to know about British birds.</a><br/></text>
```

I am wishing to set the whole content of the tag `<text>` to 11111

I'm using pythong and lxml and the following are my codes:

```
import nltk
import lxml.etree as le
current_file = '/Users/noor/Dropbox/apps/APIofLife/src/clear_description/bird.rdf'
f = open(current_file,'r')
doc=le.parse(f)
for elem in doc.xpath("//text"):
        elem.text = "11111"
f.close()
f = open(current_file,'w')
f.write(le.tostring(doc))
f.close()
```

However, after running the above codes, my results are:

```
<text>11111<br/><br/><a href="/nature/19700707">All you need to know about British birds.</a><br/></text>
```

I want to know why the whole content of the tag `<text>` has not been changed to `11111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`lxml.etree._Element` documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html), `text` property correspond to the text before the first subelement.

You need to delete sub elements:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as le
>>>
>>> root = le.fromstring('''<text>test<br/><br/>
... <a href="/nature/19700707">All you need to know about British birds.</a>
... <br/></text>''')
>>> for elem in root.xpath("//text"):
...     elem.text = '1111'
...     del elem[:]  # <----------
...
>>> le.tostring(root)
'<text>1111</text>'
```